# JSON.PARSE without loosing header array field

Tags: javascript, json

```
function main(message){
 ...
phone= JSON.parse(message.phoneNumbers);
 ... }
```

My input JSON is

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": "123 456-7890"
    }
  ],
  "children": [],
  "spouse": null
}
```

The result I receive is omitting the "phoneNumbers" but I do want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is correct, when i JSON.parse it, i get everything allright.

But you don't seem to access to your data in the right way. You must first parse the whole JSON, then you have a javascript object, and only then you can acces your property.

in detail:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(message);
var phone = obj.phoneNumbers;
```

or in short:

```
var phone = (JSON.parse(message)).phoneNumbers;
```

Comment: And if I want to access it as JS object? i.e message.phoneNumbers as the input is already a js object.

Comment: Js and Json have very similar syntax, but they are not the same. `message.phoneNumbers` is not a js object, even if it looks like, because `message` is a string, and has no `phoneNumbers` property. It only becomes a js object when parsed. As a side note: `phoneNumbers` in the Json is not itself valid as javascript code, because it has no `varName = {` before. A js interpreter would throw an error for the `:` character.